# How can you read all the sheets in a spreadsheet individually?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently I am only able to read the first sheet of my spreadsheet  ("General"), my spreadsheet consists of the following sheets "General", "Errors" and "Sheet3".

Currently I have managed to save all the available sheets names to an array "pages", I then check to see if there are values in "Pages", If so I then remove the value at position 0 and return it ("General" Sheet) and shift the values at the remaining indexes down, I then check to see if the returned page is equal to the "General" sheet if so the general sheet is read, however once the general sheet is read i want to be able to read the rest of the sheets using the same function.

So what I would like to achieve would include calling the readPages() function and have it read all the sheets within my spreadsheet.

```
function readPages(sheets, spreadsheetId, pages) {
  if (pages.length) {
    var page = pages.shift();

    if (page === "General") {
      //read general
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
        {
          spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
          range: "General"
        },
        (err, res) => {
          var values = null;

          if (err) {
            console.log("Problem reading" + page);
          } else {
            console.log("reading " + page);
            values = res.data.values;
            values = readGeneralSheet(values);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      //read rest of the sheets
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
        {
          spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
          range: page
        },
        (err, res) => {
          var values = null;

          if (err) {
            console.log("Problem reading" + page);
          } else {
            console.log("reading other sheet " + page);
            values = res.data.values;
            values = readGeneralSheet(values);
            values = readSheet(values, res.data.values);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  } else {
    //finish
    console.log("no more pages to read");
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to correctly understand your question. So can I ask you about `read all the sheets in a spreadsheet individually` of your goal? By understanding it, I thought that I might be able to think of the solution.

Comment: of course! so what I'm wanting the readPages() function to achieve is to firstly check there are any values left in the "pages" array, then remove the first value in the array and to check if that value is equal to "General", if that value is equal to "General" then I want to call the readGeneralSheet() function. Once the "General" sheet has been read I would like to iterate through the remaining sheets left in the  "page" array one by one. Sorry if my explanation isn't clear but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please check whether my understanding for your question is correct. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, could you please help me understand your goal? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this answer because I think you may have a flawed understanding of sheet identity and retrieval.

In this answer, 'getSheets' retrieves all the sheets. The following line of code (taken from the documentation) merely lists the sheet name of the second sheet (since the sequence number starts from zero).

The second element of the answer is a loop that runs through the values of "sheets" (from `geSheets` and puts those values into an array. Now the array (Pages) contains all the names of the sheets).

The third element is a second loop (which could have been combined with the first loop) which retrieves every sheet name and uses `getSheetByName(name);` to make the sheet active. From here you can do anything you want in the sheets.

---

```
function so5734222601() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  if (sheets.length > 1) {
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The active sheet is = "+sheets[1].getName());
  }
  pages=[];

  // loop through the sheets and assign to an array called pages.
  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet#"+i+" = "+sheets[i].getName());
    pages.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: example: sheet#0 = "+pages[0]);

  //loop through the sheets
  for (z=0;z<pages.length;z++){
    var sheetname = pages[z];
    var thesheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    Logger.log("DEBUG: The current sheet = "+thesheet.getName());
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

---

REFERENCES
[getSheetByName(name);](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
[getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

> what I'm wanting the readPages() function to achieve is to firstly check there are any values left in the "pages" array, then remove the first value in the array and to check if that value is equal to "General", if that value is equal to "General" then I want to call the readGeneralSheet() function. Once the "General" sheet has been read I would like to iterate through the remaining sheets left in the "page" array one by one.

From your above [replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342226/how-can-you-read-all-the-sheets-in-a-spreadsheet-individually?noredirect=1#comment101194081_57342226), I understood like below.

- When the first element of `pages` is `General`,

  - You want to retrieve values from the sheet of `General` and run the function of `readGeneralSheet(values)`.
  - You want to retrieve values from the sheets except for `General`.
- When the first element of `pages` is NOT `General`,

  - You don't want to retrieve the values.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, when the first element of `pages` is `General`, all values from `pages` are retrieved. Then, each value are separated. By this, I think that the process cost can be reduced.

#### Modified script:

```
function readPages(sheets, spreadsheetId, pages) {
  if (pages.length && pages[0] === "General") {
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(
      {
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        ranges: pages
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        const values = res.data.valueRanges;

        // "General" sheet.
        const generalValues = readGeneralSheet(values.shift().values);
        console.log(generalValues);

        // Other sheets.
        const valuesOfOtherSheets = values.map(e => e.values);
        console.log(valuesOfOtherSheets);
      }
    );
  } else {
    //finish
    console.log("no more pages to read");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Values of the sheets except for "General" are put in 2 dimensional array.

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)